# Changing Theme of complete Application

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am creating a application where I want to change the Theme of complete application. i.e If I click on any `Button` say changeTheme the it should change the theme w.r.t `Application` `Context`.

I tried

```
OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme1);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        }
    };
```

But this is not reflecting. Is there any modifications which I need to put so that I can change the `Application` `Themes`

Adding styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme1" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: apply theme in manifest in application tag

Comment: @Raghunandan I have applied theme in manifest file. but i need to change the theme Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

java as follows

Utils.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
public class Utils
{
     private static int sTheme;
     public final static int THEME_DEFAULT = 0;
     public final static int THEME_WHITE = 1;
     public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;
     /**
      * Set the theme of the Activity, and restart it by creating a new Activity of the same type.
      */
     public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
     {
          sTheme = theme;
          activity.finish();
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
     }
     /** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
     public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
     {
          switch (sTheme)
          {
          default:
          case THEME_DEFAULT:
              activity.setTheme(R.style.FirstTheme);
              break;
          case THEME_WHITE:
              activity.setTheme(R.style.SecondTheme);
              break;
          case THEME_BLUE:
              activity.setTheme(R.style.Thirdheme);
              break;
          }
     }
}
```

and use it as follows

```
Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_WHITE);
```

you can write a click event as follows

```
@Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          switch (v.getId())
          {
          case R.id.button1:
          Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_DEFAULT);
          break;
          case R.id.button2:
          Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_WHITE);
          break;
          case R.id.button3:
          Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_BLUE);
          break;
          }
     }
```

you can have theme style as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="FirstTheme" >
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SecondTheme" >
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Thirdheme" >
        <item name="android:textColor">#0000F0</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

For complete example please visit http://mrbool.com/how-to-change-the-layout-theme-of-an-android-application/25837

Comment: This will be applied for particular Activity and not for the complete Application.

Comment: yes for a layout so for each one you can set progrmatically!!

Comment: what can be another solution is try in the same way and do it from Application class of yours project!!

Comment: Theme can be set for activity as well as application. If I set it for Application context then for e.g. all textview colors in the application will be changed. No need to do it for every activity

Comment: yes you are write also visit http://www.anddev.org/applying_a_theme_to_your_application-t817.html